# Convex approximation of an expression

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy, approximation

I am trying to transform an expression given by

$$ \operatorname{trace} \left( {\bf{X} } \right) +  \left( \sum_{n=1}^N \mathcal{R}(x_n) \right) $$ into convex from where $\mathbf{x}$ is complex in nature, size (1,N).

Comment: is that real part? What is the relation between $X$ and $x_n$? No one can help you id we don't' know what the expression is, including unstated relations between the symbols.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo you shared a related answer to above question, can you reshare ?

Answer (score 2):

No approximation is needed if you wish to minimize the expression.  For maximization, see the material after "Edit".

Due to cyclic permutation invariance of trace,
$$\text{trace}(X) = \text{trace}(xx^H) = \text{trace}(x^Hx) = x^Hx$$ the latter two of which will be accepted by CVX, CVXPY, CVXR, and similar convex optimization tools.

Presuming you want to minimize the expression, the CVX code is:

```
cvx_begin
variable x(N) complex
minimize(x'*x + sum(real(x)))
% add constraints
cvx_end
```

If you wish to maximize the expression, that would be a non-convex problem. Per your comment, you do wish to maximize, so I am adding the contents of my first answer, which I had deleted.

**EDIT**:  OP wants to maximize, per comment. So here is what can be done in that case.

A convex SDP relaxation can be used which will provide an upper bound on the optimal objective value of the original maximization problem.

Specifically, $X = xx^H$ is relaxed to $X \succeq xx^H$.

Here is CVX code for this.

```
cvx_begin sdp
variable X(N,N) hermitian
variable x(N) complex
maximize(trace(X) + sum(real(x)))
[X x;x' 1] >= 0
% add other constraints
cvx_end
```

If the solution $X$ is rank one, the solution to the relaxed problem is optimal for the original problem. Otherwise, the optimal objective value of the relaxed problem only constitutes an upper bound for the optimal objective value of the original maximization problem.

Comment: I am maximizing this expression.

Comment: @ Muhammad  I just edited my answer to add the convex SDP relaxation approach (which I had in my original answer, which I deleted) to handle maximization..

Comment: How can we justify that if $\mathbf{X}$ is related to $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^H$ and [X x;x' 1] >= 0 only enforce the positive semi definiteness, but we can not say $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are related.

Comment: That's why it's a relaxation. Therefore as a maximization problem,, unless that semidefinite constraint is satisfied with singularity (i.e., LHS - RHS is singular, i.e., optimal X is rank one), the optimal objective value only provides an upper bound for the optimal objective of the original problem.

Comment: Thanks. It's more clear now. Why can't we take $\mathbf{x}$ as the optimal value as it is rank-1? Instead of getting a rank-1 solution from $\mathbf{X}$ using some randomization methods. And also is the optimization variable.

Comment: Using x by itself (as $x^Hx$( without X for the non-convex maximization problem; it is s non-convex; you can solve that, but not by convex optimization. if you do wish to use convex optimization, x by itself could be anything;l it is the relation to X which matters. and gives it any possible meaning.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, what if i want to add another constraint in the above implementation, Let say $|(\mathbf{x})|^2  \leq a/b + \mathcal{R}(\mathbf{x}) $. where a and b are scalars and $\mathbf{x} \in C ^N$

Comment: `x'*x <= a/b + sum(real(x))` )or whatever that last term is really meant to be.

Comment: Can I use $\mathbf{V} = [ \mathbf{X} \mathbf{x}; \mathbf{x}^H 1]$ as an optimization variable in the above problem how does CVX know the structure of my optimization variable $\mathbf{V}$ Because if I can do that then there will no issue with relation between $\mathbf{X}$  and $\mathbf{x}$. I am not able to find a way to deal with that because the rank-1 solution from $\mathbf{X}$ and the solution we get for $\mathbf{x}$ should be the same.

Comment: $V$ is an expression built up out of variables. The relation between them is provided by the semidefinite constraint `[X x;x' 1] >= 0`. However, that is a relaxation of$X = xx^H$ and doesn't guarantee the solution will satisfy that equality, i.e., a rank one solution.

Comment: You can't get something for nothing, as you are seeing with that second constraint.. The absolute value in the objective places the problem into the same non-convex situation as addressed by the semidefinite relaxation approach to the maximization problem, which results in a convex problem, the solution of which does not solve the original problem unless that solution is rank one.

Comment: 1. Is there any way around approximating abs()?  2. Can you elaborate on the last line of your comment? 'The solution of which does not solve the original problem unless that solution is ranked one.' Similar to the above, I have to ask 'x'*x >= a/b + sum(real(x))' in this non-convex constraint as well, where a and b are scalars.

Comment: Use a non-convex solver.